# Wiring Issues with Sparkfun Oled

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm attempting to hook up an arduino uno with a Sparkfun Oled. I downloaded the example program and made these changes:

```
#define PIN_RESET 3  // Connect RST to pin 3
#define PIN_DC    4  // Connect DC to pin 4
#define PIN_CS    10 // Connect CS to pin 10
#define DC_JUMPER 0
```

I connected everything according to Sparfun's walkthrough. I also wired accordingly. However, I cannot seem to get the Oled to do, well, much of anything. I have tried switching the MOSI and MISO to see if that makes a difference, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

I'm using:
pin 13 - clock (in the picture I was trying pin 8 for the clock but I have tried both)

pin 12 - MISO

pin 11 - MOSI

pin 10 - CS

pin 4 - DC

pin 3 - RESET

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong? I've tried to figure it out for a good long while now and I can't make the display do anything productive.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you inspected the pins you soldered on for cold joints?

Comment: It looks almost like the wires are simply pushed through the holes of the OLED breakout board (i.e. not soldered at all). If that's the case then there's a good chance they aren't forming a reliable connection.

Comment: If I only want to test the oled without committing it to an actual application, is there any way I could do that without soldering?

Comment: (Old thread, but still.) This picture doesn't provide any useful information. Either draw a schematic or use something like Fritzing to create something legible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you connected the `GND` pin from the `UNO` to the breadboard?  I can't hardly tell.  But it looks like you are also using 5V to power it?

How are you powering the `UNO`?  Is it just 3.3V?  I'm powering mine with a 5V but have level converters connected.

Mine:

[image: UNO with OLED]